# Xml editing problem using C#

Tags: c#, xml, filestream, edit

I have posted a question previous regarding editing my xml document via c#

[C# write to XML error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158894/c-write-to-xml-error)

However im now having trouble with it again. Im using the exact code that worked then but getting problems again!

When I first click the button it seems to work however when I click it again I get the error

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 83, position 10
```

When you then open the XML document for some reason the characters "ï»¿" get added to the start of the xml document so I get

```
"ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"
```

I dont understand why and its really driving me insane. I'm sure it was working before.

My code:

```
path = test.xml

using (FileStream READER = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                System.Xml.XmlDocument Temp = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                Temp.Load(READER);

                using (FileStream WRITER = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    Temp.Save(WRITER);
                }
}
```

Comment: The two strange characters you see are byte markers that indicate the encoding of the XML file for applications wanting to read the file. You should not worry about them. 

What error do you get?

Comment: What encoding format are you using for your textfile?

Comment: its an xml file  I get the error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 83, position 10

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE #2**:

I compiled your sample as is and it worked perfectly for me. I tested it with a file created straight from code and also with a xaml file created in Visual Studio. So it seems the file you're working with is corrupted or have an encoding problem.

As far as I know you can't do anything about corrupted file, but as for encoding you can specify it when reading by using a StreamReader object. You just pass a desired encoding and your reader stream to StreamReader's constructor. Also it has an option to detect the encoding from byte order marks.

```
using (TextReader txtreader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251 /*desired codepage here*/)))
        {
            document.Load(txtreader);
        }
```

or

```
using (TextReader txtreader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), true /*tries to detect the encoding*/))
        {
            document.Load(txtreader);
        }
```

Of course, you should save the file using the same encoding or you'll have problems next time you run your loading code.

Also I'm attaching a code which creates a file if it doesn't exist or just modifies it if it already exists.

```
class Program
{
    static readonly string path = @"C:\Users\Dmitry\Documents\test_3.xml";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            test(path);
    }

    static void test(string path)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (Stream readStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                document.Load(readStream);
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            document.AppendChild(document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", String.Empty));
            document.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("Test"));
        }

        document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("Node"));

        using (FileStream WRITER = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            document.Save(WRITER);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: For example this way: Temp.Save(new XmlTextWriter(WRITER, Encoding.UTF8));

Comment: that didnt work that just messed up the xml document completely. I figured out whats happening. Its fine the first time i edit it but then if i try and edit it again without closing the program then it writes to the end of the xml file so I get a load of rubbish tags at the end which dont apply to anything. So my xml document becomes unusable. Im guessing this is because I'm not closing the file stream somehow but I've tried putting reader.close() and writer.close() but nothing works

Comment: When you exit your using() block, your Stream is closed. (Usually you want you stream to be closed as soon as you end doing IO, so I'd suggest closing using() for reader stream after Temp.Load). I updated my answer with a working example of repeated Xml editing.

Comment: Also, it seems that there is some perk with the XmlTextWriter, so I've just deleted it from my original answer.

Comment: getting the error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 83, position 10. again this time on the first time i click the button

Comment: I didn't write file creation. So you normally should provide it with a valid xml file. You can create it in notepad or check if the file exists and if not add a root element etc instead of loading. I'll update my answer later.